# Do the database specific Types go in Domain Model or Data Access Layer?

Tags: c#, java, domain-driven-design

I have my entities such as Customer, Order etc. defined in my Domain Model.

Now I want to define an interface called IRepository to represent my persistence layer, i will further have SQLRepository, CacheRepository which implement IRepository.

Now i'm wondering if I should define IRepository in the Domain Model or the Data Access Layer? I guess SQLRepository and CacheRepository needs to go in the DAL, but does IRepository go in there too?

Further, for example my Repository returns a list of Customers from the Customer table, i'm a bit confused about how to design this, it seems like i end up repeating types in DAL and Domain Model. See example below:

**In the application i want to do something like this :**

```
var repository = new SQLRepository();

//Below repository.customers represents customer table
List<Customer> customers = repository.Customers.list();
```

**So In my Domain:**

```
class Customer
{
  public int id;
  public string name;
}
```

**In my DAL:**

```
class SqlRepository:IRepository
{
   public CustomerTable Customers;
}

class CustomerTable 
{
   public List<Customer> list();
}
```

I wanted to know if there's a better way to design these layers?

* UPDATE

I already have the DAL and the Domain defined in different class libraries/assemblies. Initially i thought i will have POCO entities like Customer which represent one record in the database table, but then where do declare Customer.Add(customer) ? does it go in DAL ? I don't want business rules in DAL, if i start adding methods in my Entities they become complex having persistance logic as well as business logic in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following information is for another problem it shows you a simple project structure: [Placing Model in separate assembly](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2010/03/23/placing-model-in-separate-assembly.aspx)

My opinion is that the IRepository interface should be public in your DataLayer project. The implementations can be private (use a Factory or Dependency Injection to load them in other projects) and the Domain Model you create can be shared by your Business Layer and Data Layer.

Comment: My thinking also- separate the layers in their own assemblies if possible.

Comment: Yes I would separate the layers into different assemblies. This will also give you the opportunity to distribute the layers over physical tiers.

Comment: I already have the DAL and the Domain defined in different class libraries/assemblies. Initially i thought i will have POCO entities like Customer which represent one record in the database table, but then where do declare Customer.Add(customer) ? does it go in DAL ? I don't want business rules in DAL, if i start adding methods in my Entities they become complex having persistance logic as well as business logic in them.

Comment: Entities shouldn't have persistance logic. Adding a customer should be a method on your repository

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing, I added the CRUD methods in the repository which work off the POCO entities. But where should I put the rules and validation? In the application itself?

Comment: Validation is something business specific. Primary and foreign key constraints will be checked by your database but business rules like: if Average(OrderAmount) > Price) { send email to ... } should be in your business layer

Comment: hmm yeah i get that my business layer will have the validation, but does my business layer only have methods which accept the entities as parameters? so like BLL.Customers.Validate(Model.Customer customer) ? Or does my business layer extend my Entities, maybe make the Entity classes partial classes?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put your types into a separate common or types assembly that's referenced by business layer and datalayer.  Be careful to limit what goes into that assembly so you don't introduce unnecessary coupling.

It's a similar approach to putting constants in a common assembly shared by a sql layer (pre-processed), business logic layer and object model ...